# How increase upload video limit on dailyMotion?

Tags: dailymotion-api

Resource upload many videos on "dailyMotion", but 4 video per hour it's really small for our resource.

**Official**, *we can upload **96** video (**4 video per hour**) and max **2000 mb**.*

My questions:

1. This limit uses for all languages or i can use this limit for each language?
2. How i can increase limit (different methods)?

Comment: You can find this information on dailyMotion. Don't bother us with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: No, this question need because i am uploading many videos uses PHP and i must know how increase limit. I have to take into account the this limit when i will be uploading new video on service.

Comment: I not found in official documentation how i can upload more video than 4) And i wrote my question here)

Comment: I deleted tag "PHP") i hope it will help my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to "dailyMotion" support and per day i got response.

I quote from response message:

> You can only send 96 videos and/or 2hrs per 24h on Dailymotion and a
> maximum duration of 60 minutes per video. We suggest you wait before
> proceeding to a new upload, but you can still watch videos and post
> comments.

Solved!